# jQuery Wordpress Codrops Adaptive Gallery Pile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to implement the jQuery plugin here (http://tinyurl.com/omntnbc) into my Wordpress site (http://www.uk2cuba.co.uk/gallery/). I've got the following code in my Header -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.uk2cuba.co.uk/wp-content/themes/salient/css/custom2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.uk2cuba.co.uk/wp-content/themes/salient/css/stapel.css">
<script src="http://www.uk2cuba.co.uk/wp-content/themes/salient/js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
```

and the following in my footer -

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.uk2cuba.co.uk/wp-content/themes/salient/js/jquery.stapel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {

            var $grid = jQuery( '#tp-grid' ),
                $name = $( '#name' ),
                $close = $( '#close' ),
                $loader = $( '<div class="loader"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>Loading...</span></div>' ).insertBefore( $grid ),
                stapel = $grid.stapel( {
                    onLoad : function() {
                        $loader.remove();
                    },
                    onBeforeOpen : function( pileName ) {
                        $name.html( pileName );
                    },
                    onAfterOpen : function( pileName ) {
                        $close.show();
                    }
                } );

            $close.on( 'click', function() {
                $close.hide();
                $name.empty();
                stapel.closePile();
            } );

        } );
</script>
```

but all I get it the loading animation. It seems jQuery is already loaded from an existing plugin but deactivating all of them does nothing, as does removing the jQuery link above.

I'm also getting a Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'prefixed' error in the Chrome Console.

In dying need of a little guidance. Thank you.

Comment: You have declared a JQuery function `jQuery(function() {`. In this function, you have written some code to load your pics. The problem is that your function is never called =/. Just try to replace `jQuery(function() {` by `$(document).ready(function(){`. It means that all the code you have written will be called once the page will be completly loaded and rendered. (Edit : Also, you seems to have an error in your DOM. You have a nested <ul class="tp-grid"> in a <ul>)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TCHdvlp, I've since managed to sort it out. :) I had my jQuery Header script in the wrong place!